# How to get a layout like this in .cshtml

Tags: html, css, .net, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller

[image]

Hi,

How do I get a layout like in the picture?
When I expand the Accordion control on the right side , the left side panel shouldnot change.Please help.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `legend` and `fieldset` tag with form.

Use `.row` class as the parent class of `col-6` and add form tag in that.

Visit for more information https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_fieldset

**Example**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <form>
           <fieldset class="border p-2">
              <legend class="w-auto">Personalia:</legend>
              <label for="fname">First name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
              <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
        <form>
           <fieldset class="border p-2">
              <legend class="w-auto">Personalia:</legend>
              <label for="fname">First name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
              <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
              <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try fieldset tag.

Answer (score 0):

For left side panel, I tried this and it works.

```
<!--First row starts here-->
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom:8px;margin-left:-350px;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;">
    <div class="col-sm-2 required;">
        <label>
            col 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 required">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.FormCode, new { id = "formcode", @class = "txtboxclass1" })
    </div>
 </div>
 <!--First row ends here-->
```

How do I align Expand 1 and Expand 2 columns properly? I tried modifying above code as below, but when I click the expand button its making the left side controls to come down

```
<!--First row starts here-->
<div class="row" style="padding-bottom:8px;margin-left:-350px;font-family:arial;font-size:15px;">
    <div class="col-sm-2 required;">
        <label>
            col 1
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 required">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(c => c.FormCode, new { id = "formcode", @class = "txtboxclass1" })
    </div>

    <div id="dvAccordian">
        <div class="col-sm-2 required">
            <a href="#">Template Code</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 required">
            <aClick Here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--First row ends here-->
```